# Jquery .animate() for scrolling left and right not working in Firefox but fine in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

The following jquery doesn't work in firefox but works perfectly in chrome. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/linddss/q4haaey6/) for fiddle example. Any ideas?

```
$('#next').click(function() {
          event.preventDefault();
          $('#imageSlider').animate({
            marginLeft: "-=200px"
          }, "fast");
       });
$('#prev').click(function() {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#imageSlider').animate({
        marginLeft: "+=200px"
      }, "fast");
   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to remove `event.preventDefault()`. You are getting an error in Firefox:

> event is not defined

because you are not passing `event` as a parameter to your callback function. Chrome is just being fault tolerant by not stopping JavaScript execution.

Code should be like this:

```
$('#next').click(function(event) {  // Notice how I passed event as a parameter
          event.preventDefault();
          $('#imageSlider').animate({
            marginLeft: "-=200px"
          }, "fast");
       });
```

Comment: Your solution worked as well. I'm still not entirely understanding why I would or wouldn't need event.preventDefault();

Comment: @linddss What it does is prevents the default action from happening when you click the element. [Here's the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault). In your case, it might not be necessary to use it unless you changed the next and previous elements to be anchor/a elements. But, the reason your script was breaking was because it was undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Works great, thank you. Can you explain what that line is used for. I got this working code form another Stack Overflow question and don't 100% understand it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 1):

Remove event.preventDefault(); and thus it will work.

Here's the updated code:

```
$('#next').click(function() {
    $('#imageSlider').animate({
        marginLeft: "-=200px"
    }, "fast");
});

$('#prev').click(function() {
  $('#imageSlider').animate({
    marginLeft: "+=200px"
  }, "fast");
});
```